# Address Book retrieve chosen phone number?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, peoplepicker, abpersonviewcontroller

I am getting on OK with my Objective C learning but have hit a bump in my app.

Below is the code I have so far, just a simple one button app with the plan to be that clicking the button will open the contacts, let you select a contact and then choose a specific number from those available which is saved as the text of a field eventually. I have got this far but I get as far as clicking the number within the contacts list and nothing happens.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,   ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
- (IBAction)myButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)myButton:(UIButton *)sender {
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker =
[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker
   shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
return NO;
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)pickershouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson :
(ABRecordRef)person  {

NSString* name =
(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);

ABMutableMultiValueRef phones =
ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray *numbers =
(__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phones);

ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSString *addresses =
(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emails);

NSString *note =
(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty);

NSLog( @"name = %@, numbers = %@, email = %@, note = %@",
      name, numbers, addresses, note );

//    WANT TO MAKE FOR EXAMPLE ( myTextField.text = CHOSEN NUMBER OF CONTACT

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: How/where are you presenting your `ABPersonViewController` once you've selected a contact?

Comment: @Marco Where the code currently says for example NSString *note =
(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty); I am instead going to have something along the lines of NSString *chosenNumer = NUMBER CHOSEN BY USER FROM CONTACT

Comment: hope that makes sense? This is where I am lost :S The final hoped result is that a user can choose a contact, then choose one of that contacts numbers which is then put into a text field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, declare  your conformance to `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` in your .h file.

Second, implement the following `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` callback method in your class to enumerate the selected contact's phone numbers:

```
#pragma mark - ABPersonViewControllerDelegate protocol conformance

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
{
    BOOL shouldPerformDefaultAction = YES;

    // Perform special action if phone number was selected
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty)
    {
        CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray *phones = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);
        CFRelease(phoneProperty);

        for (NSString *phone in phones)
        {
            NSLog(@"phone = %@", phone);
        }

        shouldPerformDefaultAction = NO;

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    // Otherwise, allow the default action to occur.
    return shouldPerformDefaultAction;
}
```